# Stopping enter key submitting also stops enter key in multi line text edit

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

There are lots of solutions on the web for stopping the enter key from submitting a form. Most commonly to use `<body onkeypress = ...`

But these seem to have the undesired side effect of stopping the enter key working in a multi-line text box. Does anyone know of a way around this, so the enter key will still work in a multi-line text box?

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script language="Javascript">
    document.onkeydown = function() {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            if (document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase () != "textarea") {
                      event.preventDefault();
                      return false;
                }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Something like this?

Comment: Edited my answer not to use JQuery.

Comment: This looks good but there might be a problem with activeElement and cross browser support.

Comment: document.activeElement is supported by IE6+, FF3+, Safari 4+, Opera 9+, Chrome 9+.

Comment: By the way, this is a nice JSFiddle showing you the usage of activeElement:  http://jsfiddle.net/w9gFj/

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following (with jquery):

```
$(function(){
$('input:not(textarea)').live('keypress', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) return false;
        if (e.which == 13) e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Only input fields are targeted, not textareas.

NON JQUERY

```
 function disableEnterKey(e)
     {
          var key;      
          if(window.event)
               key = window.event.keyCode;
          else
               key = e.which;     

          return (key != 13);
     }
```

And add onKeyPress on all text inputs

```
<input type="text" name="textIn" onKeyPress="return disableEnterKey(event)"/>
```

Ref : http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/Disable-Form-Submit-on-Enter-Key-Press.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I would really prefer a non jquery solution.